# Error installing webmin on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, package-management, apache2, amazon-ec2

So I am trying to install webmin on an Ubuntu 16.04 amazon ec2 instance. I have apache2, php7, mariadb already installed. I have been using http://www.htpcbeginner.com/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu/ guide and everything has gone fine until the apt-get install when I get this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'webmin.list.' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package webmin
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
N: Ignoring file 'webmin.list.' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

The file name extension is supposed to be `.list` and not `.list.` for Apt to pick it up as a package source file.

1. Rename the file:

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin.list. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin.list
   ```
2. Update the package list based on the modified package sources:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the `webmin` package:

   ```
   sudo apt install webmin
   ```

Comment: :/ its always the smallest of mistakes lol. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the webimin ppa `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin*`

Then make sure you add correctly the ppa for installing webmin

`sudo sh -c "echo deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin.list"`

Then just do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install webmin
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remove the webimin ppa sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin*
>
> Then make sure you add correctly the ppa for installing webmin
>
> sudo sh -c "echo deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository
>   sarge contrib > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webmin.list"
>
> Then just do
>
> sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install webmin

this worked for me