# Installing Webmin on ubuntu?

Tags: server, webmin

When trying to install webmin on ubuntu I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package webmin
```

I am using this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu-16-04 and have tried it multiple times, any ideas? Oh I also have little to know understanding of things ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I had a look at the instructions, it said to add a repo to your sources; the repo was for Debian 3.1 (Sarge) [http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/dists/] which is really old. I liked webmin when I first found it, but lost interest in it [very quickly] when I realized it didn't respect the .conf file (it deleted all instructions/comments making it much harder  to document & use anything else esp. modern features).   Did you get any errors with prior commands (adding keys [apt-key], updating software-lists [apt-get update])?

Comment: no I didn't just at the end

Comment: if you want/need it in a hurry; http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/pool/contrib/w/webmin/ is where the package is. you can `wget http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/pool/contrib/w/webmin/webmin_1.880_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.880_all.deb` then continue with later steps. This however doesn't fix your issue  (why webmin wasn't found in repo's, and any updates to webmin won't be found so its no fix)  [fyi: wget downloads the  file, `dpkg -i`  does the install step ('apt-get install' does both); the '&&' means dpkg is only run IF download was complete

Comment: can you also please re-run `sudo apt-get update` and copy/paste (into the question) the lines around  http://download.webmin.com/down... as I'm stuck at thinking that is the issue (I browsed the file structure quickly & nothing stood out as wrong).  What Ubuntu are you using too please?

Comment: The 16 server. lemme finish this in the morning or the afternoon since I have school early in the morning. Oh and little to no, my grammar is currently lacking. I added the download.webmin part to the end of the list. Then the two parts after that work fine.

Comment: `Error 14 amd64 packages` then `404 not found`

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/586g0blgpyn0boe/Server.mp4 once I update. I know it seems sketchy but its the only way I could do it

Comment: An error & a 404 doesn't help me unless I get to see the reason for the error (ie. please copy & paste to your question). What I'm looking for is text, and I'll only look at a video if it can't be shown with easy-to-read-text.  Please run the apt-`sudo apt-get update` copying & pasting the text; otherwise I can only tell you there is likely error(s) in your `sources.list` file (or in its .d/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing webmin on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866477/error-installing-webmin-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score -1):

Follow the following steps:

## install wget package

```
$sudo apt install wget
```

## install webmin

```
$ wget -qO- http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc | sudo apt-key add

$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib"

$ sudo apt update
```

## now install webmin

```
$ sudo apt -y install webmin
```

installation complete.

now access with `http://localhost:10000`

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer. Also, `wget` is default to any Ubuntu I know of. And you could add the source of your information --> http://www.webmin.com/deb.html. Also, if you read the instructions OP followed, you will see that it's basically the same information.